# Python: cannot import urandom module (OS X)

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

I'm quite ashamed to ask a question like this one, but I've been trying for a couple of hours already...it seems I can't get my python version to do random things anymore. More precisely, it's missing the module `urandom`.

First, here are some info about my system:

- OSX version: 10.7.4
- python version: Python 2.7.1
- `which python`: `/opt/local/bin/python`
- `import os; os`: `<module 'os' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>`
- `echo $PATH`: `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`
- `$ENV` and `$PYTHONPATH` are empty

Now, when I have a deeper look and do `vim /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py`, I can see this file requires urandom:

```
line 47: from os import urandom as _urandom
```

So, quite logically, I have failures when I try running:

```
>>> import random
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 47, in <module>
    from os import urandom as _urandom
ImportError: cannot import name urandom
```

Any ideas? Where is urandom supposed to live? I've been googling around without success so far. 
It seems a lot of Ubuntu users had this problem with virtualenv, but I'm not using virtualenv, and I'm not on Ubuntu. My bet is that somehow my PATH or PYTHONPATH or ENV variables are not set properly, but I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.
I had a dirty hash table in my terminal.

Solution:

```
hash -r  # will erase the currently used hash table
```

Once this was done, I ran python again and I got:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 19 2012, 00:55:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> import os; os
<module 'os' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
```

Note the different python version (2.7.3 vs 2.7.1 before). I think this is due to an earlier install of python 2.3 via mac port.

Sorry for the question/quick answer :/

Have a good night! 
Arnaud

Comment: Hi Amaud, how did you find that solution?

Comment: Honestly I was kind of desperate for things I could try (2+ hours for debugging such a ridiculous problem). Then this `hash` command came to mind, I tried it, it worked. I'm afraid I don't have an awesome bug chasing story here :/

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I was completely stumped by this when it occurred during a build process (I'm not a Python guy in any case), so much appreciated. :-)