# Missing module in python

Tags: python, vim

I recently tried installing powerline-vim, but have been running into problems with it.

Every time I open a new window, I see this error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>9_UpdateWindows..<SNR>9_pyeval:
line   1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/uuid.py", line 545, in uuid4 import random
File "opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/uuid.py", line 545, in uuid4 from os import urandom as _urandom
ImportError: cannot import name urandom
```

When I delete this line from my .vimrc file (effectively disabling powerline-vim) the error goes away.

```
python from powerline.ext.vim import source_plugin; source_plugin()
```

The curious thing about this is when I fire up python from the terminal, the imports work just fine.

```
 Python 2.7.3 (default, Nov 17 2012, 19:54:34) 
 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import random
 >>> from os import urandom as _urandom
 >>>
```

The output of which python:

```
/opt/local/bin/python
```

I am running OS X 10.8.2.

Thanks!

Comment: The os module does not have urandom and python is installed in /opt/. Have you built that python installation from sources yourself? It looks like Python build is missing some functionality due to absence of some libraries or configuration keys.

Comment: I'm running OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: Could you edit the file that imports urandom and print sys.path and os just before the failure occurs? The only thing I think it may be is that the plugin modifies sys.path (or maybe does something else in a wrong way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if your problem is related with that: [Python: cannot import urandom module (OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658141/python-cannot-import-urandom-module-os-x). Check your `sys.path` value. Make sure you import `os` module from your installation of Python, not from system Python.
2. Check the log `configure` generates when you build Python for clues. Have you specified prefix when building Python?
3. Edit the code and print `os` and `sys.path` just before the error occurs to check if the plugin changed something. If sys.path is modified, often you may find the place where it is by performing `import sys; sys.path = tuple(sys.path)`. It does not crash on `sys.path = smth`, but crashes on `append()` and `+=`. Maybe that would be enough to show the place where `path` is modified.

Comment: >>> os.path
<module 'posixpath' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
My os.path appears to be consistent.

Comment: Sorry, sys.path, of course. My mistake. And where is os module taken from?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was executing the wrong version of Python.

```
sudo port select python python27-apple
```

Running that line fixed it.

Thanks!