# Python version, "2.7.2+", what does the plus mean?

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

I have a virtual environment that I installed some time ago. When I activate it and run python I'm told that the version number is

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08)
```

What does the plus after the version number mean?

And could that somehow explain why the function `os.urandom` is not defined, even when (according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.urandom)) it has been there since version 2.4.

```
>>> from os import urandom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name urandom
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/general.html#how-does-the-python-version-numbering-scheme-work):

> You may also find version numbers with a “+” suffix, e.g. “2.2+”.
> These are unreleased versions, built directly from the CPython
> development repository. In practice, after a final minor release is
> made, the version is incremented to the next minor version, which
> becomes the “a0” version, e.g. “2.4a0”.

---

And for your second question, the inability to import urandom in a virtualenv is a known problem.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366919/815632) to a similar question should be helpful.