# Can't import modules in python without sudo - ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, permissions, ubuntu-12.04

I feel like this is a new issue since I upgraded to ubuntu 12.04.

Now, if I enter the interactive shell and import a standard module like `urllib2`, I get the following error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
   import httplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 79, in <module>
   import mimetools
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
   import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
   from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 47, in <module>
   from os import urandom as _urandom
  ImportError: cannot import name urandom
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in     apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, urllib, re, pwd, grp, os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 47, in <module>
    from os import urandom as _urandom
    ImportError: cannot import name urandom

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 79, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 47, in <module>
from os import urandom as _urandom
ImportError: cannot import name urandom
>>>
```

If I run sudo before entering the interactive shell, everything is fine, it imports without throwing a fit.

I don't want to just chmod 755 my entire /usr/lib/python2.7 directory, so what can I do to make things run more smoothly in a more sensible way?

Comment: what do you get if you do `ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py` and `ls -l /dev/urandom`?

Comment: Are you running from a virtualenv or anything?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25769 Aug  1 00:39 /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py
&
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 9 Sep 12 03:31 /dev/urandom

Comment: @Thomas I have not been using it consistently, so effectively no, though I know i should.

Comment: sorry, no idea then. You seem to have the right permissions to access the necessary files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python ImportError cannot import urandom Since Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366821/python-importerror-cannot-import-urandom-since-ubuntu-12-04-upgrade)

Comment: @tripleee I would love it if that thread solved my problem, but it does not. I don't know if it's completely independent of virtual environment, but none of the fixes in that thread or subsequent resources has worked for me, still have the problem noted above.

Comment: @dqo; if you run the same code from within a Python script, do you still receive the error?

Comment: @Sam yes. though if i run it with sudo, script runs fine.

Comment: @dqo and there's no chance that you have 2 versions of Python installed, right? I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS too, and do not have such problems.

Comment: If you want to see if the OS complains about anything, you could run your program with strace, that should be able to show permission problems, missing files, etc.

Comment: ok running virtualenv over my home dir has worked to solve this issue. but this has brought me to the conclusion that my python setup is a total mess. thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Virtual Machine. That will give you a clean environment unhampered by past installs.